# Change rel="noopener noreferrer" to rel='noopener noreferrer' (single quote)

Tags: html

I am using a carousel plugin to display images, when I click an image it opens a lightbox with the image and the caption (text) underneath it. But when I want to add HTML to the caption it doesn’t work unless I use single quotes on the HTML. But when I add

```
    target='_blank'
```

WordPress automatically adds

```
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
```

which is double quote and that doesn’t work on the lightbox. Is it possible to make that single quote and would it still be safe to use single quote on rel="noopener noreferrer".

Thank you.

Comment: I'd guess this is [wp_targeted_link_rel_callback](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3239) and you can see that the double quotes are hard-coded in there in core code. The best you could do with this probably is to drop them altogether by hooking the wp_targeted_link_rel filter and returning an empty string, which will stop that code adding these. However obviously you then lose the rels throughout.

Comment: However I'd guess this is an escaping problem in the carousel plugin, so I'd look at the generated code to see if you can work out why the quotes are breaking this and either talk to the authors of the plugin or try and fix it yourself.

Comment: The double quotes are indeed hard-coded, is it possible to change that? Another option is to disable it and add it myself. But the author of the plugin says he has no solution (or time) so that is no option)

Comment: Not in a way that would survive a core update, no. But you're right: you could make your own versions of wp_targeted_link_rel, wp_targeted_link_rel_callback and wp_init_targeted_link_rel_filters, then call wp_remove_targeted_link_rel_filters() to remove the existing filters and your own init function to add your version that uses single quotes.